# How to manually report an input tag to the user via JS?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

Basically I want to create an effect like the one you get with required attributes:
[image: an example of the required attribute]

[(example from w3schools.com)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required)

But since I'm not able to use something like `type="email"`, because my patterns differ (and sometimes the input is used to add elements to an array), I want to check the validity manually via JavaScript and, if the inputted data isn't right, report it to the user as shown above.

Any ideas how to do it are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oninvalid` and `onvalid`

```
<input id="username"  type="text" required="required"
       oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Your alert')"
       onvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')">
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work.

```
const button = document.getElementById('btn') //use id of the button
button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
function handleButtonClick() {
   const inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value
   if (inputValue != null || inputValue !== '') {
      //do your logic here
   }
}
```